# How do you make 111 1.11 in Python 3

Tags: python, formatting

How do you make a random integer like 14562 become a float with 2 decimals like 145.62?

```
import random

r = random.randint(1,5000)
```

What would I print in here to achieve that goal?

```
print(?)
```

Comment: Just to clarify this program is with python 3.x

Comment: um, divide by 100?

Comment: `Python 3` division returns `float` by default unlike `python 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just divide it by 100:

```
print(r/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. 
        `print(float(r))`

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more general, if you want to print a value with *n*-digits, then you need to print

```
print(r/10**n)
```